# Prevent VSCode auto add empty newline after <?php, and before comments

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, autosave

When I write in a php file the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Comments....
```

the VSCode autoformat on save like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Comments....
```

I don't want this auto empty newline.

The "problem" is detected only after the combination of <?php and /** comments.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

not sure how to really say this in a completely understandable way, but you need to edit the formatter configuration that you use in vscodes settings. Or you can install a different formatter and use that instead with its own config

Comment: I use PHP Intelephense